# Создание БД в MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

проблема в следующем:

есть файл db.sql с нижеприведенным содержимым.
После

```
$query = file_get_content('db.sql'); 
mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
```

Выдает: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */; /*!40101 SET @OLD_CHAR' at line 13

Насколько я понял mysql_query() образает запрос. потому как в $query попадает полностью все содержимое файла, которое приведено ниже.

Вопрос: как быть??

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 3.3.10
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
--
-- Хост: localhost
-- Время создания: Апр 07 2011 г., 20:17
-- Версия сервера: 5.5.10
-- Версия PHP: 5.3.6

SET SQL_MODE="NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";

/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;

--
-- База данных: `default`
--
CREATE DATABASE `default` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
USE `default`;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Структура таблицы `audio`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `audio` (
  `audio_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `module_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `bitrate` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`audio_id`),
  KEY `fk_audio_module1` (`module_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;

--
-- Дамп данных таблицы `audio`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Структура таблицы `catalog`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `catalog` (
  `catalog_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `parent_catalog_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `info_unit_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `unit_type_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `hide` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `have_unit` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`catalog_id`),
  KEY `fk_catalog_unit1` (`info_unit_id`),
  KEY `fk_catalog_catalog1` (`parent_catalog_id`),
  KEY `fk_catalog_unit_type1` (`unit_type_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='<double-click to overwrite multiple objects>' AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;

--
-- Дамп данных таблицы `catalog`
--

INSERT INTO `catalog` (`catalog_id`, `parent_catalog_id`, `info_unit_id`, `unit_type_id`, `hide`, `have_unit`) VALUES
(2, NULL, 2, 2, NULL, NULL);

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Структура таблицы `css`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `css` (
  `css_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `css` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`css_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;

--
-- Дамп данных таблицы `css`
--

INSERT INTO `css` (`css_id`, `css`) VALUES
(1, 'align-ri'),
(2, 'align-lf');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Структура таблицы `element`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `element` (
  `element_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `element_type_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `unit_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `value` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`element_id`),
  KEY `fk_element_unit1` (`unit_id`),
  KEY `fk_element_element_type1` (`element_type_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='<double-click to overwrite multiple objects>' AUTO_INCREMENT=8 ;

--
-- Дамп данных таблицы `element`
--

INSERT INTO `element` (`element_id`, `element_type_id`, `unit_id`, `value`) VALUES
(3, 6, 8, 'newtestsite'),
(4, 6, 9, 'newtestsite'),
(5, 6, 10, 'newtestsite'),
(6, 6, 11, 'newsite'),
(7, 6, 12, 'newsite');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Структура таблицы `entry_point`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `entry_point` (
  `enttry_point_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `module_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `pint_ind` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `include_module_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`enttry_point_id`),
  KEY `fk_entry_point_module1` (`module_id`),
  KEY `fk_entry_point_module2` (`include_module_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

--
-- Дамп данных таблицы `entry_point`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Структура таблицы `free_file`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `free_file` (
  `free_file_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `size` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`free_file_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

--
-- Дамп данных таблицы `free_file`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Структура таблицы `image`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `image` (
  `image_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `module_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `width` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `height` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `background` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`image_id`),
  KEY `fk_image_module1` (`module_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;

--
-- Дамп данных таблицы `image`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Структура таблицы `map`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `map` (
  `map_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `page_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `module_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`map_id`),
  KEY `fk_map_page1` (`page_id`),
  KEY `fk_map_module1` (`module_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

--
-- Дамп данных таблицы `map`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Структура таблицы `module`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `module` (
  `module_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `module_pattern_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `section_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `css_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`module_id`),
  KEY `fk_module_module_pattern1` (`module_pattern_id`),
  KEY `fk_module_section1` (`section_id`),
  KEY `fk_module_css1` (`css_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;

--
-- Дамп данных таблицы `module`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Структура таблицы `page`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `page` (
  `page_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `meta` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`page_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;

--
-- Дамп данных таблицы `page`
--

INSERT INTO `page` (`page_id`, `title`, `meta`) VALUES
(1, NULL, NULL),
(2, NULL, NULL),
(3, NULL, NULL);

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Структура таблицы `section`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `section` (
  `section_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `catalog_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `section_type_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`section_id`),
  KEY `fk_section_catalog1` (`catalog_id`),
  KEY `fk_section_section_type1` (`section_type_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=6 ;

--
-- Дамп данных таблицы `section`
--

INSERT INTO `section` (`section_id`, `catalog_id`, `section_type_id`) VALUES
(5, NULL, 6);

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Структура таблицы `unit`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `unit` (
  `unit_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `unit_type_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `catalog_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `hide` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `comment` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`unit_id`),
  KEY `fk_unit_catalog1` (`catalog_id`),
  KEY `fk_unit_unit_type1` (`unit_type_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=13 ;

--
-- Дамп данных таблицы `unit`
--

INSERT INTO `unit` (`unit_id`, `unit_type_id`, `catalog_id`, `hide`, `comment`) VALUES
(2, 1, 2, NULL, NULL),
(4, 4, NULL, NULL, NULL),
(5, 5, NULL, NULL, NULL),
(6, 4, NULL, NULL, NULL),
(7, 4, NULL, NULL, NULL),
(8, 4, NULL, NULL, NULL),
(9, 4, NULL, NULL, NULL),
(10, 4, NULL, NULL, NULL),
(11, 4, NULL, NULL, NULL),
(12, 4, NULL, NULL, NULL);

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Структура таблицы `var`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `var` (
  `var_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `module_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `section_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `value` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`var_id`),
  KEY `fk_var_module1` (`module_id`),
  KEY `fk_var_section1` (`section_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

--
-- Дамп данных таблицы `var`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Структура таблицы `video`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `video` (
  `video_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `module_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `width` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `height` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `pre_image` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `bitrate` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`video_id`),
  KEY `fk_video_module1` (`module_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;

--
-- Дамп данных таблицы `video`
--

--
-- Ограничения внешнего ключа сохраненных таблиц
--

--
-- Ограничения внешнего ключа таблицы `audio`
--
ALTER TABLE `audio`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_audio_module1` FOREIGN KEY (`module_id`) REFERENCES `module` (`module_id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION;

--
-- Ограничения внешнего ключа таблицы `catalog`
--
ALTER TABLE `catalog`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_catalog_unit1` FOREIGN KEY (`info_unit_id`) REFERENCES `unit` (`unit_id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_catalog_catalog1` FOREIGN KEY (`parent_catalog_id`) REFERENCES `catalog` (`catalog_id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_catalog_unit_type1` FOREIGN KEY (`unit_type_id`) REFERENCES `onpages`.`unit_type` (`unit_type_id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION;

--
-- Ограничения внешнего ключа таблицы `element`
--
ALTER TABLE `element`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_element_unit1` FOREIGN KEY (`unit_id`) REFERENCES `unit` (`unit_id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_element_element_type1` FOREIGN KEY (`element_type_id`) REFERENCES `onpages`.`element_type` (`element_type_id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION;

--
-- Ограничения внешнего ключа таблицы `entry_point`
--
ALTER TABLE `entry_point`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_entry_point_module1` FOREIGN KEY (`module_id`) REFERENCES `module` (`module_id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_entry_point_module2` FOREIGN KEY (`include_module_id`) REFERENCES `module` (`module_id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION;

--
-- Ограничения внешнего ключа таблицы `image`
--
ALTER TABLE `image`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_image_module1` FOREIGN KEY (`module_id`) REFERENCES `module` (`module_id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION;

--
-- Ограничения внешнего ключа таблицы `map`
--
ALTER TABLE `map`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_map_page1` FOREIGN KEY (`page_id`) REFERENCES `page` (`page_id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_map_module1` FOREIGN KEY (`module_id`) REFERENCES `module` (`module_id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION;

--
-- Ограничения внешнего ключа таблицы `module`
--
ALTER TABLE `module`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_module_module_pattern1` FOREIGN KEY (`module_pattern_id`) REFERENCES `onpages`.`module_pattern` (`module_pattern_id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_module_section1` FOREIGN KEY (`section_id`) REFERENCES `section` (`section_id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_module_css1` FOREIGN KEY (`css_id`) REFERENCES `css` (`css_id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION;

--
-- Ограничения внешнего ключа таблицы `section`
--
ALTER TABLE `section`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_section_catalog1` FOREIGN KEY (`catalog_id`) REFERENCES `catalog` (`catalog_id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_section_section_type1` FOREIGN KEY (`section_type_id`) REFERENCES `onpages`.`section_type` (`section_type_id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION;

--
-- Ограничения внешнего ключа таблицы `unit`
--
ALTER TABLE `unit`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_unit_catalog1` FOREIGN KEY (`catalog_id`) REFERENCES `catalog` (`catalog_id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_unit_unit_type1` FOREIGN KEY (`unit_type_id`) REFERENCES `onpages`.`unit_type` (`unit_type_id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION;

--
-- Ограничения внешнего ключа таблицы `var`
--
ALTER TABLE `var`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_var_module1` FOREIGN KEY (`module_id`) REFERENCES `module` (`module_id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_var_section1` FOREIGN KEY (`section_id`) REFERENCES `section` (`section_id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION;

--
-- Ограничения внешнего ключа таблицы `video`
--
ALTER TABLE `video`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_video_module1` FOREIGN KEY (`module_id`) REFERENCES `module` (`module_id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION;
```

Comment: Опечатка: там разумеется file_get_contents(..)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[mysql_query](http://ua.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) не поддерживает выполнение нескольких запросов одновременно. Попробуйте использовать расширение [mysqli](http://ua.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) и его [mysqli_multi_query](http://ua.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php).
Можете считать это 5-м пунктом ответа ling :)

Comment: А mysqli поймет комментарии? Или их все равно придется обрезать?

Answer (score 4):

Спешу вас огорчить: дамп БД - это не один большой mysql запрос. И mysql_query не может выполнить больше одного запроса за раз. Есть несколько выходов из этой ситуации:
1) Закинуть/импортировать дамп через phpmyadmin.
2) Найти какой-нибудь скрипт типа mysql dumper, позволяющий копировать/восстанавливать БД.
3) Воспользоваться запросом к mysql через командную строку (что точно писать, я не помню, но это легко гуглится).
4) Написать собственный скрипт: получить содержимое файла, отбросить все строки начинающиеся на "--", разбить файл по ";n", обработать массив и выполнить запросы по отдельности.

Comment: =(( и правда огорчил.. так лень эти фигульки писать и искать. Но спасибо за ясность, ling. Возможно когда нибудь и я тебе помогу)

Answer (score 3):

Я в своих проектах пользую sypex dumper для импорта дампов, очень нравится, особенно для дампов более 10 мб.
[>>>sypex dumper](http://sypex.net/)

Answer (score -1):

Делайте так:

```
shell_exec("mysql -u root -h localhost -p databasename < db.sql");
```